# How to list logs ordered by most recent in a log group in AWS CloudWatch?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-sdk-js

Using the Javascript SDK for CloudWatch, I can't figure how to list logs in a log group by timestamp descending. I need to get the last logs for a whole log group (representing a Lambda function).

The FilterLogEvents request don't seem to offers this possibility. It seems possible while requesting logs directly inside a log stream but it is not convenient as I need to get the last logs for the whole log group. I also don't want to use CloudWatch Logs Insights as it doesn't seem to be adapted for "application use-case" (I need to integrate these logs into multiple clients apps).